# Altium designer mass component changes in library

Tags: altium

I want to modify the description and name of a number of components in schematic library.
How can I do that effectively?
Right now, I have to do it manually which is not really nice to do because I have thousands of components.
For example, I want to delete the description of these components:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely Altium is scriptable?

Comment: You will either have to do this by hand or by script, I'm fairly sure this is doable by script

Comment: Sorry I haven't heard of the scripting thing before. I have to try them out :D

Comment: You can copy-paste the contents to an Excel spreadsheet. Either work in Excel or convert the Excel format to plain text to edit. In the future, consider using an Excel include file (Tools -> Update Parameters From Database) as it is more efficient for single users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** The SCHLIB List panel is probably a good place to start. See the official documentation here:
https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/sch-pnl-schliblistschlib-list-ad

Open a SchLib file, then open the SCHLIB List panel and select `Edit` `all objects` from `all components` include only `Parts` at the top of the SCHLIB panel:

[image]

That should get you started, and allow you to edit the descriptions like a spreadsheet.

**Option 2:** The Parameter Manager tool is another way to do this. Again the official documentation is here:
https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/workspacemanager-dlg-parametereditorformparameter-table-editor-ad

With a Schlib open navigate the menus to `Tools -> Parameter Manager...`. In the Parameter Editor Options Panel, check **only** `Parts` in `Include Parameters Owned by` section.   Make sure `Exclude System Parameters` is **not** checked (i.e. you want to include system parameters) in the `Other Options` section:

[image]

Press `OK` and you should be able to modify the 'Description' under the `System Parameters` sub-column. Then be sure to `Apply Changes` and complete the ECO process...

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying this out